# Self modifying code - iPhone

Tags: iphone

After reading this wikipedia article :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code

I am wondering if this technique has been done on iPhone.

Thanks

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

A standard iPhone application is unable to set a memory page as executable. So, it's impossible to modify your own code or generate code at runtime (ie.: Just In Time compilation).

A jailbroken device will allow you to have such pages though.

Comment: thanks.
My goal was to find a way to securing a library which my application was compiled with. Any idea ?

Comment: You want to obfuscate the code in your library so people won't reverse engineer it?

Comment: Well, if it's a standard C or C++ library, symbolic information shouldn't appear in the binary generated by the Release configuration. It should be enough to stop anyone who doesn't have knowledge of the ARM architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Not allowed by apple, and I believe it's physically prevented, the code space can't be modified, and code cannot run from the data space. (Jailbreaking could fix this however)

Answer (score -3):

```
Three things that are most trecherous:
Connectors that corrode
Recursive algorithms 
And self modifying code 
         -- traditional programmer's chanty
```

Self modifying code is the easiest and surest way to make code behavior completely unpredictable. It's something that is interesting academically but it is seldom a practical tool.

As near as I can tell, it's primary use is to wreak vengeance on an employer when you know you're going to be fired.

Comment: The first one holds up--connectors that corrode are no good. The others do not. Self-modifying code is used frequently without widespread ills. JIT-based VM's rely heavily on it. DTrace, virtualization software, and many debuggers patch code freely and PIC is a common optimization technique for dynamic VMs. Lastly, recursive algorithms form the foundation of theoretical computer science and are generally more amenable to formal reasoning than iterative alternatives. This quote may have made sense 30 years ago, but it's obsolete today.

Comment: The chanty doesn't say the techniques are not useful, it says they are "treacherous" which they are. Recursive algorithms can easily spiral out of control which is why Lisp never caught on like it theoretically should have. Self-modifying code is likewise a easy way to shoot yourself in the foot.